# Why the following inequality holds?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $E$ be a complex Hilbert space and $(A_1,...,A_n) \in \mathcal{L}(E)^n$.

> If $(\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_n)\in \mathbb{C}^n$, why
>   $$\left\|\sum_{k=1}^n\lambda_kA_k\right\|\leq \left(\sum_{k=1}^n|\lambda_k|^2\right)^{1/2}\left\|\sum_{k=1}^nA_kA_k^*\right\|^{1/2}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $x\in E$. Then applying Cauchy-Schwarz and elementary calculations we get
$$
\begin{split}
\| \sum_k \lambda_k A_kx\|^2
&= \langle (\sum_j \lambda_jA_j)x,\  (\sum_k \lambda_k A_k)x\rangle\\
&= \sum_{j,k} \lambda_j \bar\lambda_k\langle A_jx,A_kx\rangle\\
&\le \sum_{j,k} |\lambda_j|\cdot |\lambda_k| \cdot \|A_jx\|\cdot \|A_kx\|\\
&=\left( \sum_j |\lambda_j| \|A_jx\| \right)^2\\
&\le\left( \sum_j |\lambda_j|^2 \right) \left( \sum_j \|A_jx\|^2 \right)\\
&\le \left( \sum_j |\lambda_j|^2 \right) \|x\|^2 \cdot \|\sum_j A_j^*A_j\|,
\end{split}
$$
which proves the claim.